# Leave empty line if text not present

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a list look consistent. However, each title has a different length. I want to make it look consistent- regardless of content.

I am trying to do the following:

1. Limit text to a maximum of two lines of text (with "..." to indicate text cut short)
2. If text is less than two lines, leave a line empty
3. Stay vertically centred

https://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/pPOQEg

I have tried, but been unsuccessful:

```
.mdl-list__item-primary-content {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

or

```
.mdl-list__item-primary-content {
    line-height: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Screenshot for clarify:
[image]

Comment: Look into using `:empty` for problem 2. (css).

Comment: can you not just give it a height instead of a line-height?  If it is a span, you may need to make it inline-block too

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you meant by 'verticaly centred' because you're taking the trouble to add a second line to fill the gap.
But otherwise you can add this to the CSS of your container to solve problems 1 and 2.

```
white-space: wrap;  
height: 2.1em;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

[Try it !](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFPLMZJ1ALHE)

Comment: Nope, this didn't work for my situation . Did it on my codepen here: https://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/pPOQEg

Comment: I just tried it, there is your solution :
add `<div>` around your text and 
`div {
  white-space: wrap;  
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}`
in your css.

And i'm currently searching for the third problem.

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt ellipsis only works on a single line, OP wants to allow a max of 2 lines

Comment: @Pete, if you add `display: -webkit-box; -webkit-line-clamp: 2; -webkit-box-orient: vertical;` ellipsis will work on two lines. Three if you set `-webkit-line-clamp` to 3, and so on.

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt that would only be for webkit browsers though so you would need to point that out

Comment: Nope, this doesn't leave an empty line